# What's the maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In the days of SQL Server 2000 and 2005, [the maximum number of tables in a query was 256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432/95).

Does MySQL have a similar limitation?

*I know that such query of such size means that either there's something wrong with database design or some data warehousing solution should be used, but let's forget about this for a while and focus on theoretical capabilities of MySQL.*

Comment: Just FYI - that 256 table limit was for SQL Server 2005. It's now limited only by server resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: @BrentOzar That's a very old question, possibly one of those posted during the beta period to seed DBA.SE with content. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the issue! I edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Limitations of Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html)

In MySQL (4.0, 5.0, 5.5), the maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is **61**. This also applies to the number of tables that can be referenced in the definition of a view.

Comment: thanks for posting!  I had 68 joins.  No wonder why my query didn't work.  LOL!

Comment: JK :-) ... HAHA